# Passing backend express session variable to Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, pug

Current code:

```
<div ng-controller="HeaderCtrl" class="header">
  <div class="logo">intquest</div>

  <div ng-if="signed_in" class="header-actions">
    <a href="/#/random">Random</a>
    <a href="/#/add">Add question</a>
  </div>

  <div ng-if="!signed_in" class="header-actions">
    <a href="/#/register">Register</a>
    <a href="/#/login">Login</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to somehow pass my Express session var to the `$scope.signed_in` variable.  Because this is an HTML and not a Jade template, I couldn't use `JSON.stringify`, I don't have a backend API so I don't think I can make a `$http` or resource request, how should I go about doing this?  What are the best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two things, assuming you can't create a backend API:

1. **See if a cookie exists.**  Try injecting the [`$cookes`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) service into your `HeaderCtrl` and examining it to see if your Expression session left any cookies.  If you did and you know its name (looks like it's `'connect.sid'` from [this](https://github.com/expressjs/session) -- unless you overwrote the default value) then just set `$scope.signed_in` to an expression that returns whether or not the cookie is present with that name.  This assumes that the cookie is not present when logged out.  I don't know if this is assumption true or not.
2. If that doesn't work, **try to read a value from the cookie if you absolutely cannot make an API call** I think you may need to make sure the cookie doesn't have a secret, etc. - then I would assume it would be readable from the client/within Angular.

Let me know if both of those don't work or if you can't/don't want to do them (and why) and I'll see if I can think of an alternative (based on your why/constraints).